# How to delete commits from git on Github and Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket, commit

I accidentally pushed up files from my .idea directory in my Django project which I had in my .gitignore file. I am trying to completely delete the commit from my bitbucket repository since there is someone else Im working with on the project and he can't pull my changes without affecting his own .idea files. I have seen other SO questions where they say to use git revert, however I remember there was another command where you pushed the last good commit you made, and everything after that was deleted from the master branch. For example

Commit History:

94ca48e

55fab05

3813803

I want to delete 94ca48e, and 55fab05. There was a command I found once where you could make 3813803 the most current commit, and everything in the remote repository after that commit would be deleted, but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `git reset --hard 3813803`. This *can not be undone* and works locally as well as remote.

For remote push using `git push --force origin master`

Have  a look at the git docu by Atlassian [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset).

Let me also quote from there:

> Whereas reverting is designed to safely undo a public commit, git reset is designed to undo local changes. Because of their distinct goals, the two commands are implemented differently: resetting completely removes a changeset, whereas reverting maintains the original changeset and uses a new commit to apply the undo.

`git reset` is the one to be used here, though, because you are asking for complete deletion.

Comment: I think it worked locally cause it says "Your branch is behind 'origin/Summer2016' by 4 commits, and can be fast-forwarded." but how do I do I do the same remotely ?

Comment: @TimothyJosephBaney: Use `git push --force origin master`.

Comment: Keep in mind this all is not so much of a good idea if you are not alone on your repo!

Comment: Phwew thanks harmonica, git always scares me when something goes awry. Thankfully the commits were the two latest ones in the remote git repository so it didn't affect anyone else on the repo.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [GitPro][1] then. It's a nice to read documentation book that you can officially download for free. [1]: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: @Sumit That should be a separate answer. It did what was needed for me.

Comment: If the mis-push included secrets, be aware that this does _not_ delete the commit from Bitbucket per se. If there's an open PR, the ID is still visible in the log, and the link resolves to show the diff.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the commits are HARD reset, unwanted commits would still show up in the history. If the history also needs to be reset, then I am afraid only way to do that is to delete and recreate the branch.