# Bitbucket deleting commits

Tags: bitbucket, commit, git-commit

I have a problem, I've committed some code and now I want to delete this commit, but this is not the last commit in whole project.[image]

I want to delete whole blue branch( if its possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem with git rebase -i id of last right commit, then you can delete commits that you don't want to see , then git push -f origin master

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the commit use

```
git rebase -interactive
```

and

```
git filter-branch
```

But you'll have to recommit every commit which goes after the commit you want to delete.

Or if you just want to remove the changes of the specific commit will be better to use

```
git revert <hash of the commit>
```

Comment: after rebase command i have this message: " It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase."

Comment: you can undo the git rebase with

git rebase --abort

Comment: it helped, but now I have the menu where I can type commands , but I can't type anything

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the whole branch, Click the branches icon on the left side of bit bucket, it will display all the branches. There will be columns like branch, Behind/Ahead, Updated, pull req, build, Actions. Click 3 dots in action column for your branch-> choose delete branch. Keep a backup in local before deleting.

Comment: its the master branch, so i cant delete it, i just want to delete this commits, like they have never been existed,

Answer (score 0):

I recommended removing the selected commits. use this

```html
git reset --soft  <commit ID>
```

For example

```html
git reset --soft  23wfee 3eelw2 34efff
```

Then your particular commit will remove but if you don't want that commit changes then use hard instead of soft like this.

```html
git reset --hard  <commit ID>
```

Comment: will it be removed from log ? Like after reset command I have message like : the HEAD now at 12367512akjsf commit ( for example ) , but I can still see these commits in the bitbucket commit history

Comment: I think it will help. go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402396/how-to-delete-commits-from-bitbucket